# How to Build Vue 3 Vite App for production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, production, vite

I created a fresh vue project with the new version which includes vite init.

When I run `npm run build` a `dist/` is created. But when I open `dist/index.html` inside the dist folder it doesn't show anything. My question is how can I build the app and run it without any command (Building for production). Thanks

Comment: You cannot build the app and run it without any command. It's how it works in the documentation. Or do you have any information that might be helpful for your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a server, otherwise assets will fail to be found and you'll get errors and a blank page. Use `npm run preview`.

Comment: So when we run npm run preview is it loading the dist/index.html file?

Comment: Practically yes, though technically it's just serving everything in `dist`. However without running this, you're missing all the files except `dist/index.html`, which is why you had the empty page.

Comment: Note that it's *technically* possible to run an app without this using `base: './'`, but I wouldn't recommend it as you can't use more modern features that require a server (such as client side routing in the path).